# How to make callbackFlows main-safe?

Tags: android, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines, suspend, kotlin-flow

In my `ViewModel` I have to call a repository function that exposes a `callbackFlow`.

Normally I would have the suspend function in repo classes wrap their code block in a
`withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { }` block.
Or if I want to make a Flow main-safe I could also use the `.flowOn()` operator, but that api isn't available with callbackFlows.

So my question is 'how do I make the use of callbackFlows main-safe?'... assuming they aren't out of the box.

Comment: what do you mean by "`flowOn` isn't available with callbackFlows"?

Comment: `flowOn` is certainly available with callbackFlow

Answer (score 0):

`callbackFlow` is a builder function, which creates a cold `Flow`:

```
fun doWork(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow<String> {
    // ...
}
```

Created `Flow` is safe to use from any coroutine:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    doWork().collect {}
}
```

You can also use `flowOn()` function to change the context where this flow is executed:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    doWork().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect {}
}
```

Comment: Lint says **applying `flowOn` to StateFlow has no effect**